# How to create multi store/branches for showing products?

Tags: multistore, store-view, multidomain, magento1.9.3

I want to create website for one shop who is having two branches in different areas. Once the user visit the site, they have to select the branch of the shop. Products have to display according to each store.

Can anyone give me suggestions how to do this?

Comment: You can create multi website and give customer option to select website by dropdown or other UI.

Comment: which means multi store view?

Comment: check my answer and let us know if you faced any issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is standard feature of Magento.

You can create multis-stores/multi-websites in admin and can assign different products to each store.

You can display a pop-up page on loading of site and can give option to chose from 2 store. And you can load specific stores accounting to selected choice of customer.

Below are few links to create multi-stores and you can create with ease.

- https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/30/How-To-Setup-Magento-With-Multiple-Stores-And-Domains
- https://www.templatemonster.com/help/magento-how-to-set-up-and-manage-multiple-stores.html#gref
- http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-set-multiple-websites-with-multiple-store-views-in-magento/

Comment: Yeah. I have created multiple website and store views as per the steps in the above link and also I have created separate root category too for that websites. But after viewing the new created website, its not showing that particular category. only default category is displaying.

Comment: Did you select separate categories in creating stores? It must work and if its not then something is missing. Please check and let me know again. Also run CLI clean,flush cache, upgrade,compile and deploy.

Comment: Its working fine with the usage of third link. I have created three stores separately. Now I need to show 3 tabs to select the particular store by adding html page. Can you help me how to integrate html page as a homepage?

Comment: ( 1 ) Create a block ,containing your HTML code inside
( 2 ) Than create a widget , select CMS Static Block as type and your theme
( 3 ) Assign your block and update layout in bottom , defining for specific page.....select page......then select container...... your can show many block this way by sorting their order on any page

Comment: Its working fine